# Two TCL scripts that use the same conection

Tags: connection, tcl, ethernet

I am working with two tcl files. One is a program that connects to a thermal scanner to get information from it via ethernet. I have integrated the other tcl GUI that can reflash the scanner via ethernet. How do I use the connection from the first one to use the flash utility on the second GUI? At first, the two GUI's were separate but I had to combine them for customers.

-let me know if you need any code, the programs are about 4000 lines long so I didnt want to put them on here.

Comment: Are you looking to factor out the connection code or are you looking to share the actual connection in a single process?

Comment: I dont really need to share it, i need one connection, then if i need the other GUI to flash the memory I need the connection the first one is using. Then after the memory is flashed switch back to the original one.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "connection". Are we talking TCP connection to a specific service port? And is the service port that is used to obtain the thermal scanner data different from the service port used to reflash the scanner? I'm confused :)

Answer (score 0):

A single TCP connection can only really be used by one process (at each end) at a time; trying to do otherwise causes confusion. Can you just get each program to talk to the thermal scanner directly? At least *theoretically,* it ought be able to support multiple simultaneous connections, and that'd be a simple way to work.

But if the device won't work that way, the easiest way to multiplex the communications is to have a single process that actually talks to the device and for the other programs to talk to that multiplexer process (probably via a local socket). The multiplexer doesn't need to have a GUI, but would be told to do things like “flash this file to the scanner” or “stream values out of the scanner”. The details of how to do all this will depend very much on what's actually going on with the communications, but the `fcopy` command is highly likely to be useful in this, as it can be used to efficiently stream data from one Tcl channel to another.

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long for me to answer; I've been thinking about this on and off and trying to come up with a way to write a sensible answer, but we're really lacking a bit too much information to give you more than general design advice.